# SQL rename column fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to rename column output from MS SQL. I would like to remove Mac OS X 10 before outputting result, i.e.

[image]

When I google this, I only get how to rename column name of a table, http://www.1keydata.com/sql/alter-table-rename-column.html

Please guide

Comment: You want to remove it from the results?  There are plenty of ways to do this - you could use a `REPLACE` in your `SELECT` statement to remove that part of the string, for example.

Comment: Have you tried using Replace function?

Comment: I didn't know about Replace function, I'll check this

Comment: By the way which database you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Replace` function in your `select` or `update` query

The syntax is:

```
REPLACE( string1, string_to_replace, replacement_string )
```

It depends on what you need to do. You can use replace since you want to replace the value:

```
select replace(old_column, 'Mac OS X 10.', '')
from yourtable
```

Then to UPDATE your table with the new ending, you would use:

```
update yourtable
set column_name = replace(column_name, 'Mac OS X 10.', '')
```

Comment: Your answer worked, i.e. `REPLACE(dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM,'Mac OS X 10.','')`